# push notification vibrate option

Tags: php, iphone, notifications, push, vibration

I am trying to implement push notification for iPhone in php. I have done by the following code:

```
 $body['aps'] = array(
                'alert' => $message,
                'badge' => 1,
                'sound' => 'default'
                );
```

This is sending alert, badge and sound options. Now, how to send the vibrate option?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, you cannot set the notification to vibrate the phone, read more from [vibrate in push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345559/vibrate-in-push-notification)