# How can I create iOS push notifications that don’t vibrate?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I know how to create silent push notifications (with playing a sound file that is silent).
I would also like to send a push notification that doesn't vibrate phone.

When setting silent sound file as suggested below phone still vibrates when it is locked or when the app is not active.

My payload that still vibrates:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            "loc-key" = "SOME_KEY";
        };
        badge = 1;
        sound = "silence.caf";
    };
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: sound = ""; Try this one :)

Comment: @DavidR. He was asking about "send a push notification that doesn't vibrate phone."

Comment: Yes i need to know how to turn off vibration.

Comment: yeah, i can understand his question. Same thing i want to told just put silence sound. if sound is there so device is not vibrating

Comment: sound="" is not working, phone still vibrates.

Comment: See my answer below. You have to omit the entire `sound` key, then no sound will be played. Setting `sound=""` is interpreted as a non-existing file, which will lead to the default sound being played.

Answer (score 12):

Omitting the sound key should do the trick:

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"SOME_KEY"}, "badge":1}
```

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) state that "If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played.". What they don't say is that if you don't provide a sound key at all, no sound will be played. If no sound is played, the phone should not vibrate as well.

Comment: Confirming this worked for me also. I had a similar issue, where I registered for Sounds when registering for pushNotifications, but not including a 'sound' key in the apns payload. When a notification came, there was no vibrations. When we included the 'sound' key, but with a blank string, the notification vibrated the phone / apple watch. Hope this helps anyone having this similar problem!

Comment: it doesn't work anymore I suppose. I sent the alert body only like this {"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"SOME_KEY"}} and vibration occurred anyway even if there was no "sound" key specified.

Comment: @wildmonkey That's sad news. On which version of iOS have you got that result?

Comment: @TammoFreese I'm currently testing on iOS 8.4

Comment: @OxenBoxen how can i set for No vibrate only get sound ? i want only sound no vibrate....

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way: server send a push to device with sound file name which is silent.
That's it.

Example:

Incomming payload from server:

```
{ aps = { "content-available" = 1; sound="silence.mp3" }; data-id = 1234; }
```

And device handle it in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSInteger data_id= [userInfo[@"data-id"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Data-id: %i", data_id);
    //
    //  code...
    //
    // UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData/UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed/UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: It still vibrates (ios 7.1) when phone is locked and therefore - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions is executed.

Answer (score 0):

when you register for push notification don't ask for sound type (`UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound`)

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types
```

you can test this by manually removing the sound permission in the notification settings

Comment: But what if i wanted to have some types of notifications with sound and some without sound and vibration?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

Please try to register for remote notifications using above code applicationDidFinsihLaunching method of AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with similiar issue. Vibration can be fixed by setting  background fetch in project capabilities