# Make iphone vibrate on receiving pushes

Tags: objective-c, notifications, push-notification, push

Is there a correct method to put the vibrate phone method in when user receives push? didreceiveremotenotification is called when the user taps the push banner so that isn't what i want. I need a method that is called immediately when the push comes to the phone.

Also, from testing on my iPhone 5c, pushes don't vibrate if the app isn't in the foreground. Is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vibrate in push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345559/vibrate-in-push-notification)

Comment: Yeah it's just the answer that starts: "I just figured out one way to do this: if" sounds like such a hack. Shouldn't I be scared to try that in a shipping application?

Comment: there may be no way to do this...

Comment: Well it doesn't sound like they'd change this behaviour soon. Anyway in fact it is some kind of hack to make phone vibrate but not use sound. However you didn't write you don't want sound, so I don't think that's the particular answer for you :) To have both sound & vibration the user have just to enable the sound for your app notifications

Comment: But if the app is in the background and I enable sounds, it doesn't vibrate when the banner comes up. Is that just an unchangable feature?