# how to turn on or off while we receive push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

in my application, i need to put a switch for notification settings. I put a sound switch so when a switch is off and I will get a notification, the sound will not come. this is working because when a sound switch is off I am sending JSON without sound.
Now I want same functionality for vibration. when vibration switch is on my device should vibrate when I receive a push notification and it should not vibrate when my vibration switch is off.

Comment: try this solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345559/vibrate-in-push-notification

Comment: Put to audio files , one is sound one is silent audio file , send empty file name in notification when you dont need to play sound.dont need to add any check or condition

Comment: @chiragshah Thanks, it seems to works for me. but in one scenario I only need sound and no vibration is there any solutions for that?

Comment: @matloobHasnain how can I handle when I only need sound no vibration

Comment: sound file only

Comment: @GovindRakholiya if you want sound then in sound parameter put the sound file otherwise used vibration file

Answer (score 0):

**First of all import these:**

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox
```

**Then write this code in switch action for vibration:**

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```