# Is it possible to vibrate only on Push Notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, usernotifications

I know how to use vibrate in in the foreground. I want to know how to use it in the background...

I searched a lot in stackoverflow but I didn't find the right answer, only an answer from 2011, where you use a silent soundfile ([vibrate in push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345559/vibrate-in-push-notification)).

If the sound of the iPhone is turned on, can you make the iPhone vibrate only on a push notification? Is the silent soundfile the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the silent sound file to vibrate still works with iOS11.

Make sure you request the `sound` attribute for your notifications.