# iOS phone, notifications in background it's not vibrate?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I develop flutter project and I use FCM and Local Notification I have issues when iOS phone in background it's not vibrate.

my BackgroundHandler:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await setupFlutterNotifications();

  showFlutterNotification(message);
}
```

I use

```
await Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
```

to vibration.`your text`

Answer (score 1):

In my opine you can't because notification **vibrate** is depends on **phone settings** so you can't do that even forcefully if notification vibration disable from phone settings.

for more details check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680502/vibrate-on-push-notification-in-ios-depend-on-client-side-or-payload) it may helpful.